# AngularJS filter true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter based on an accountID and I only want one record to come back at a time.  I have the following code where if I set the filter: query: true, then no data shows.  This happens when I add true to the ng-repeat.  Why is it bringing back no records when I set it to true?  Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="LookUpCtrl as vm">
<div>
    <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query.accountId" />
</div>
 <div ng-if="query" ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter: query : true">
        <div class="col-lg-4"><h2>{{result.accountName}}</h2></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"><h2>[{{result.ordernumber}}]</h2></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">Images go here</div>
  </div> 
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, I can now see why your data is not appearing when filtering by the accountId. The value in your response object is an integer and the input for comparison in the text box is a string. This will never evaluate to true when doing a strict search. I was able to get it correctly filtering in your plunker when the accountId value is a string. There are a few new objects in your array testing that.

```
{
  accountId: '3',
  ...
  name: 'Mr. This'  
},
{
  accountId: '4',
  ...
  name: 'Mr. That'
},
{
  accountId: '44',
  ...
  name: 'Mr. This'
}
```

Here is the updated link with your plunker (updated to load angular and the app). Please disregard my re-configuring of the controller structure..

http://plnkr.co/edit/eZUayzldWmSEOjnkPceZ?p=preview

Comment: I added <div class="col-lg-6"><h2>{{ result.accountId }}</h2></div> in my ng-repeat, but it is still bringing back nothing when I have true set in the filter.  Am I adding it correctly?

Comment: That looks correct but, is accountId displaying anything before you attempt the search filtering? I get the sneaking suspicion that it's either not in your result object or improperly named.

Comment: can you look at my plunker?  http://plnkr.co/edit/vpqDw3q9OBHfodUFxSWu?p=catalogue

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde Out of respect for your answer, I will address your question. When I began editing, your answer was not as it is now. It took me a while to update my edit since I was doing it on my iphone and not a computer. When I was finished, I didn't check your answer to see if it had changed. I like that we both came up with the same issue with the code and you have actually given a better solution allowing for not changing the object value type.(upvoted) There was no copying of your answer and if you feel I have wronged you, I welcome you contacting the moderators for support on this.

Answer (score 2):

At the official AngularJS documentation there is an example of how you should use filters and the explanation of what the `comparator` is (in your case `true`).

Here is a plunker with an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cv3B1j?p=preview

When you set the comparator to `true` as the documentatio says: *"This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual."* This means that what you write in the searchbox must be exactly the same as the field in the object you are filtering.

If you want you could provide a plunker so it is easier to reproduce your error and solving it.

**EDIT:**

Now I understood your problem. Here is a working plunker of it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pFd5bOmnm2nEL98TJgi5

The problem was that your Id was a number and not a string.

If you still want to manage your ids as numbers, you could set an input of type number an it will work. 
`<input type="number" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query.accountId" />`

Comment: I've created a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/vpqDw3q9OBHfodUFxSWu?p=catalogue

Comment: your plunker is empty?

Comment: Sorry, I had copied a wrong link, now it is updated. But your plunker is nos working, please provide a working example.